# How to Combine Multiple WITH and MATCH clause in Cypher Neo4j

Tags: docker, neo4j, cypher

I am working on a question consist of two different parts related to each other. I want to combine both of them.

1: First Part

```
MATCH (r:Route)-[source_Airport_ID]->(a:Airport)
with count(r.SourceAirportID) as cnt, a.AirportID as          
NumberofAirports_Having_source_flightGreater300
where cnt>300
Return Count(NumberofAirports_Having_source_flightGreater300)
```

2: Second Part

```
MATCH (r:Route)-[destination_Airport_ID]->(a:Airport) 
with count(r.SourceAirportID) as cnt, a.AirportID as  
NmberofAirports_Having_destination_flightGreater300
where cnt>300
Return Count(NumberofAirports_Having_destination_flightGreater300)
```

3: Combine Part

```
MATCH (r:Route)-[source_Airport_ID]->(a:Airport) 
with count(r.SourceAirportID) as cnt, a.AirportID as   
NumberofAirports_Having_source_flightGreater300
where cnt>300

MATCH (r:Route)-[destination_Airport_ID]->(a:Airport) 
with count(r.SourceAirportID) as cnt, a.AirportID as     
NumberofAirports_Having_destination_flightGreater300,      
NumberofAirports_Having_source_flightGreater300
where cnt>300

Return      
Count(NumberofAirports_Having_source_flightGreater300),
Count(NumberofAirports_Having_destination_flightGreater300)
```

1: First one gives count 104

2: Second query also gives 104

3: But when I combine both of them answer is 10816. How to combine both and the answer still remain 104 for both?

Comment: Is it 100 or 104?

Comment: @cybersam Sorry it's 104. *Corrected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
MATCH (r:Route)-[source_Airport_ID]->(a:Airport)
with count(r.SourceAirportID) as cnt, a.AirportID as          
NumberofAirports_Having_source_flightGreater300
where cnt>300
WITH COUNT(NumberofAirports_Having_source_flightGreater300) AS cnt1

MATCH (r:Route)-[destination_Airport_ID]->(a:Airport) 
WITH cnt1, count(r.SourceAirportID) as cnt, a.AirportID as  
NmberofAirports_Having_destination_flightGreater300
where cnt>300
Return cnt1, Count(NumberofAirports_Having_destination_flightGreater300) AS cnt2
```

Comment: You should check your logic, though. Both of those sub-queries are doing exactly the same thing. `source_Airport_ID` and `destination_Airport_ID` are just used as temporary names for relationships. I hope you are just testing, or learning.